# What is Java synonym for Kotlin "as"?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have two classes:

```
BaseViewModel extends ViewModel

NetworkViewModel extends BaseViewModel
```

In Kotlin I can use this method:

```
override fun selectViewModel(): Class<BaseViewModel> {
    return NetworkViewModel::class.java as Class<BaseViewModel>
}
```

But in Java I can´t do this (incompatible types):

```
@Override
public Class<BaseViewModel> selectViewModel() {
    return NetworkViewModel.class;
}
```

In Kotlin I can use "as", but how to do it in Java?

Comment: Shouldn't the return type be `Class<? extends BaseViewModel>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any keyword in Java which is similar to the 'AS' keyword of C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219773/is-there-any-keyword-in-java-which-is-similar-to-the-as-keyword-of-c-sharp)

Comment: i think you can use the `instanceof` keyword

Comment: @diAz `instanceof` becomes `is` in Kotlin and is meant to check whether a specific object "is a" specific class (either directly or a subclass). `as` and `as?` are "cast" and "safe cast" respectively, instead

Answer (score 1):

Yes, @khelwood is right, it should be:

```
public abstract Class<? extends BaseViewModel> getViewModelClass();
```

and then I can use:

```
@Override
public Class<NetworkViewModel> getViewModelClass() {
    return NetworkViewModel.class;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in Kotlin you shouldn't be using `as` here either; your superclass should declare

```
abstract fun selectViewModel(): Class<out BaseViewModel>
```

where `Class<out BaseViewModel>` is the equivalent to Java `Class<? extends BaseViewModel>`, and then

```
override fun selectViewModel() = NetworkViewModel::class.java
```

will work.

In case you do need to cast, the equivalent to `x as SomeType` is `(SomeType) x`; but in this case you'll probably need a double cast

```
return (Class<BaseViewModel>) (Class<?>) NetworkViewModel.class;
```

because Java compiler notices `Class<NetworkViewModel>` and `Class<BaseViewModel>` are incompatible.